# How to get the last line of output with pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm trying to get the last line (after sending the command) and only the last line of the output with pexpect. command here is a parameter of the function.

```
child.sendline(command)
child.expect(command + '\r\n')

return child.after.decode("utf-8").rstrip()
```

This is the type of commands I send :

```
qdbus com.company.menu /Menu ParamName
```

I should receive an output like this (it can have spaces between words and without the linux username and hostname):

Words* (newline)

Right now it outputs the command itself.

What is wrong the my regex in the expect method?

Comment: Is Words* (newline) your command prompt?

Comment: No, it's a String output without the command prompt it's like an echo

Comment: does "the last" mean the most recent or does it mean that there is no more output? If you want the former; use `.readline()`. If you want the latter; you could call `.expect(pexpect.EOF)`. Note: [*"`.after` means after the point of match, not after the matched string."*](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html) i.e., it is expected that you should see `command`'s content in `.after`.

Comment: I execute a command and there is output with it OR not (depends on the command). I want the output of that command without the "username@pcname....". So I can get an empty string or some string.